# Run a recorded WebEx session in the normal client (i.e. not WebEx Player)

Tags: webex

I have a requirement to run test sessions with people booked onto a future WebEx training session. The purpose of these sessions is to ensure that users are able to use the WebEx software as well as to make sure their microphones and webcams are working correctly.

What I would like to be able to do is to record a session and let delegates watch it in their own time. Unfortunately, recorded sessions are delivered via the WebEx player instead of through the main application. This has two drawbacks:

1. We won't be checking the actual software they'll be using
2. As the Player has no knowledge of the user's webcam or microphone, we can't do in-session tests (i.e. "make a noise and ensure that the bar goes green")

Is there anyway to deliver pre-recorded, on-demand content to users through the normal WebEx application?

Comment: You want to play back a recorded session like it is an interactive live session? Is that what you are looking to do?

Comment: Yep. That's pretty much the crux of it.